# VS Code theme issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not sure what has happened to my theme on VS Code but before when I declared an integer it would light up into the light blue color. Now it doesn't for some reason, and I could figure out how to change it back. (My code still works and functions find)

---

[image]

As you can see the: n, n_a, and etc. variables should be a light blue color.

Comment: You can reinstall that theme.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have changed your theme, to fix this go to File > Prefrences > Color Theme or CTRL K + CTRL T to hotkey to this menu where you can select a theme. The page should look something like this seen below.

[image: Colour options]

From here either navigate to your old theme or find a new one you like. If your old theme was for some reason deleted click Install additional Color Themes and Navigate the included menu and find something similar.

For more information on creating your own theme go here - https://medium.com/wearelaika/vscode-create-your-own-custom-theme-extension-96c67bd753f6